How to select a specific object in a complex multiple objects
I am a newbie to Blender, read through how "selecting" the objects in Blender. I've couple of questions.

Take for instance a banana bunch.
How to increase the length of one of the banana in the picture to a lengthy one or a short one than the others?
To increase or decrease length, I need to select that banana, how to select only that banana leaving others?
Is it just painstakingly rotating the plane in all directions and selecting either vertices / face or select using lasso select or is there any automatic way available to select only one banana?
